# How to set up Masked Redirect with Google Cloud VM instances

Tags: google-compute-engine, domain-name, namecheap

I have a VM with multiple apps. for example: 
32.32.32.01/app1
32.32.32.01/app2
32.32.32.01/app3

I have a domain name from namecheap and I want it to use it only for app1.

so www.mydomain.com should take me to 32.32.32.01/app1.

I created URL Redirect Records on namecheap for both aliases (www and @) but it is not working.

Do I have to also do some configuration at the google cloud side?

Comment: While directly not relevant, I do recommend making sure your app also wroks with IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

You need enter via ssh to the VM, you also need a Apache http server, and create a site: ex:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo cp 000-default.conf siteName.conf
sudo nano siteName.conf
```

Add a configuration (i dont remember the exact config, but this can give you a idea of the file content)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin mail@server.co
ServerName domain.co
ServerAlias www.domain.co

DocumentRoot /var/www/site
...
```

Save the file and restart apache

```
sudo a2ensite siteName
sudo service apache2 reload
```